# List not rendering in page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, rxjs, material-ui

I am new to react and was trying to render a list in the confirm page. But it is not rendering. It is taking up the space but the elements are not rendering.

Here is the code:

```
return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className={useStyles.root}>
            <AppBar position="static">
              <Toolbar>
                <Typography
                  gutterBottom
                  align="center"
                  style={{ width: "100%", alignItems: "center" }}
                >
                  Confirm Information
                </Typography>
              </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>

          </div>

          <br />
          <h3>Are you sure to continue and confirm your information?</h3>
          <List>
            <ListItem primaryText="Departments" secondaryText={value} />
            <ListItem primaryText="Title" secondaryText={Title} />
            <ListItem primaryText="Kpi_Before" secondaryText={Kpi_Before} />
          </List>
          <br />
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            style={styles.button}
            onClick={this.continue}
          >
            Confirm & Continue
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="default"
            style={styles.button}
            onClick={this.back}
          >
            Back
          </Button>
        </React.Fragment>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }

}
```

What could be the issue?

I am using material-ui core list and list items.

Comment: Based on your observation that it 'is taking up the space' but not 'rendering', I'm guessing it's a CSS issue and the problem isn't the render but rather the display.  You can check in the developer tools of the browser to see if the elements appear in the DOM representation.  Can you share the applicable styles?

Comment: I used list item text instead and used primary and secondary to input value. It seems there is a difference between the syntax for material ui and material ui core